# OpenShift Origin V3- edge, passthrough and encrypt termination

Tags: openshift

Can someone please explain the below OpenShift Route and when to use which route.

1. passthrough
2. edge
3. encrypt

Answer (score 5):

Routes can be either secured or unsecured. Secure routes provide the ability to use several types of TLS termination to serve certificates to the client. Unsecured routes are the simplest to configure, because they require no key or certificates, but secured routes encrypt traffic to and from the pods.
A secured route specifies the TLS termination of the route. The available types of termination are listed below:

**Edge Termination**
With edge termination, TLS termination occurs at the router, before the traffic gets routed
to the pods. TLS certificates are served by the router, so they must be configured into the
route, otherwise the router’s default certificate is used for TLS termination. Because TLS
is terminated at the router, connections from the router to the endpoints over the internal
network are not encrypted.

**Pass-through Termination**
With pass-through termination, encrypted traffic is sent straight to the destination pod
without the router providing TLS termination. No key or certificate is required. The
destination pod is responsible for serving certificates for the traffic at the endpoint.

**Re-encryption Termination**
Re-encryption is a variation on edge termination, where the router terminates TLS with a
certificate, then re-encrypts its connection to the endpoint, which might have a different
certificate. Therefore the full path of the connection is encrypted, even over the internal
network.

for further details
[Openshift routes](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/architecture/networking/routes.html#secured-routes)

Comment: can you elaborate the routes with some example that would be helpful to understand.

Comment: you can find more detailed instruction here: https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.9/architecture/networking/routes.html

Comment: you might also find this article https://medium.com/swlh/understanding-openshift-route-bd973d8a620a helpful